# Как собрать несколько css файлов в один на Gulp?

Tags: gulp

Здравствуйте как собрать несколько файлов `css` в один файл при помощи `gulp` у меня есть файл `main.css` и `sprite.css`?

```
gulp.task('style', function(done) {
return gulp.src('dev/scss/**/*.scss')
    .pipe(gulpif(isDevelopment, sourcemaps.init()))
    .pipe(plumberNotifier())
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(cleanCss({compatibility: 'ie8'}))
    .pipe(shorthand())
    .pipe(purge())
    .pipe(autoprefixer({
        browsers: ['last 15 versions'],
        cascade: false
    }))
    .pipe(gulpif(isDevelopment, sourcemaps.write()))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dev/css'))
    .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream: true}));
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
npm install --save-dev gulp-concat-css

var gulp = require('gulp');
var concatCss = require('gulp-concat-css');

gulp.task('default', function () {
 return gulp.src('assets/**/*.css')
   .pipe(concatCss("styles/bundle.css"))
   .pipe(gulp.dest('out/'));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

имена файлов задаешь в стиле "_имяФайла.css"
и создаешь глобальный css фаил, туда подлючаешь все отдельные файлы командой @import, не обязательно для этого использовать галп , обычно такое используется если используется препроцессор(sass less) , для компиляции и сборки в 1 глобальном файле